# IPN simulator Error

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to implement IPN service, so I have made my own Listener (handler) and I were trying to test it with IPN simulator but i got this error:

"You have requested an outdated version of PayPal. This error often results from the use of bookmarks."

This error come in returned HTML in acknowledgement step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in appending **&cmd=_notify-validate** at the beginning of *IPN message*, the problem has been solved when I appended it at the end of *IPN message*.